# Compare two arrays, use key from array two to find value from array one

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays,

Array one:

```
$amount = array(0 => 11, 1 => 22, 2 => 33);
```

Array two:

```
$id = array(1 => 1);
```

I would like to get a result like this, by comparing:

```
result = array(1 => 22);
```

I've been trying to do this with several PHP functions, but my brain has now melted.

Hope there is some help out there.

Answer (score 2):

Though your question is bit vague I guess what you need is [*array_intersect_key*](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-key.php),

```
$common = array_intersect_key($amount,$id);
```

**[DEMO](http://codepad.org/g8NwTvMR)**.

Comment: Thank you. Id been using array_intersect() before, but thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to loop through the keys in `$id` and get the corresponding `$amount` into an array?

```
$result = array();
foreach($id as $key => $value) {
    if(isset($amount[$key])) {
        $result[$key] = $amount[$key];
    }
    else {
        // handle situation where
        // $amount doesn't have that key
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$array=array();
 foreach($id as $key=>$val){
 if(array_key_exists($key,$amount)){
   $array[$key] = $amount[$key];
 };
}

print_r($array);
```

[DEMO](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d3ff654510155c5aea51e3ca290ffa37428a96e5)